# Can't Terminate Running Task on Linux in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am unable to Terminate Running Task on Linux. I am using npm run to execute my build script which fires up webpack dev server. This keeps running until I stop it manually, which works fine on Windows, but on Linux I simply get the error "Failed to terminate running task".

There is no information printed to the console when this occurs. Anyone have a suggestion? Is there any way to get more information about why this failed?

Comment: is your question on how to kill a task or to get information on why it fails? its a bit unclear i think?

Comment: Ideally someone would already know why it fails and tell me how to resolve it. If not, some direction on how to get information on why it fails would be helpful.

Comment: maybe you dont have admin rights on the process running code.

Comment: If I run as root, this still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the issue. The terminateProcess.sh did not have executable permissions. Actually, neither did the code executable or any of the other sh files. I don't have an understanding as to why they aren't executable already when they are decompressed, but once I provided that permission, it resolved this issue.

Comment: Can you mark this answer an answer for community Wiki?